# Node.js attaching event handlers on new

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, eventemitter

In a Node.js-based project, I have a couple objects:

- `EmitterA`
- `EmitterB`
- `Consumer`

In `Consumer`'s constructor, I have the following:

```
var a = new EmitterA();
a.on('someEvent', someEventHandler);
```

In `EmitterA`'s constructor, I have the following:

```
var self = this;
var b = new EmitterB();
b.on('someEventFromB', function() {
    self.emit('someEvent');
});
```

Finally, in `EmitterB`'s constructor, I have something like this:

```
this.emit('someEventFromB');
```

The problem is that `Consumer`'s `someEventHandler()` doesn't get fired when the inital `.emit()` from `EmitterB` is fired.  The reason is one of timing.  `Consumer` doesn't subscribe to `someEvent` on `EmitterA` until **after** the event has been fired.

**Is there a way to attach event handlers at the time of construction?**  I have considered utilizing the [`newListener` event](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_newlistener), but this will be problematic when working with multiple listeners later on, and situations where there are many different types of events that will be fired.  I'd like to avoid this route if possible, and am looking for alternatives that you may suggest.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
var a = new EmitterA({
    events : {
        someEvent : someEventHandler
    }
});

function EmitterA( props ){
    props || ( props = {} );

    if( props.events ){
        for( var n in props.events ){
            this.on( n, props.events[n] );
        }
    }

    // the rest of the constructor code
}
```

Comment: Ha, yeah that would work well.  I don't know why I didn't think of that in the first place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of an alternate way that works for my specific case, but may be problematic for others.  Please use it with a grain of salt.

In `EmitterB`'s constructor, I changed `this.emit('someEventFromB');` to this:

```
process.nextTick(function() {
    this.emit('someEventFromB');
}
```

See also:  http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick